# Serve a JSON file over HTTP with Python

Tags: python, json, http

How do I serve a single JSON file over HTTP using only the Python standard library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in Python 3,
to serve the current directory:

```
$ python3 -m http.server
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html

batteries included FTW!

Answer (score 7):

Open a terminal. Navigate to the folder with the JSON file in. Run this:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Browse to:

```
http://localhost:8000/your.json
```

Enjoi!